# django ModelForm without all fields - fill them automatically

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, django-forms

I'd like to fill one field of my model automatically. It holds a client IP.

I've defined an CreateView as follows:

```
class MyView(CreateView):

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.form_class.client_ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    super(MyView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

  model = MyModel   
  form_class = MyForm
```

and MyForm in that way:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    exclude = ('ip',)
```

And I have no idea how to fill this exluded field.

Answer (score 1):

In `MyView` you should add a method called `get_initial` which returns the initial values of the form (as a dictionary). For example:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return { 'ip': ... }
```

These initial values are then used when the form is created.

Comment: But in get_initial(self) how can I get an access to client ip?

Comment: You could assign it to the view (e.g., `self.client_ip = ...`) and then use it in `get_initial`.

Comment: How can I assign it to the class based generic view? I've got a request object only in get and post methods.

Comment: You can assign it in those methods and then use it in `self.client_ip`. This is fine because a each view is used for only one request at a time. Like you have done in your `post` method, you should assign it there and then call the `get` or `post` in the super class.

Comment: Yes, but it looks that it doesn't work if the ip field was excluded.

Comment: In that case you should include the field but use a `HiddenInput` widget to display it. The field will be in the form but the user won't be able to fill it in.

Comment: It is some kind of solution, but for me it has a serious disadvantage. Client can easily change value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

excluded fields have be to manually filled. you can look into the middleware processors that can add to the `request.POST` dict and you can override the `__init__` on the `MyForm`, [first call super] and then set the model's `ip` field. 
the middleware processor can also add to `POST` some other request level attributes, making it available for future use.